# adding a column to a table in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to use 2 date columns in my table to calculate and display the difference in time between these 2 dates in a 3rd column. However the result i am not getting the expected solution.
diff_minutes is a function to calculate the time difference between 2 input 2 dates.

I am new to angular and not getting a solution around this.

i tried to calculate the column separately but was unable to bind it to the main table

```
this.Tabletodisplay = this.tabledata.map( o => { o.TAT = 
this.tabledata.map(TAT => 
this.diff_minutes(TAT.Last_Modified_Date,TAT.Create_Date))
```

--HTML Segment

```
    <div>
        <mat-card class="mx-auto" style="margin-top: 2rem; width:100%;">
          <mat-card-title>Table List
        </mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-content>
            <div id="SummaryTable2">
              <nz-table #TTSummaryTable2 [nzData]="this.listOfIDsFollowUp" [nzLoading]="isLoading" >
                <thead style="font-style:bold">
                  <tr>
                    <th style="width: 300px;">ID</th>
                    <th style="width: 200px;">Created At</th>
                    <th style="width: 200px;">Last Update Time</th>
                    <th style="width: 200px;">TAT</th>

                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let data of SummaryTable2.data" 


                    <td>{{ data.CaseId }} </a></td>
                    <td>{{ data.Last_Modified_By_User |date: "medium"}}</td>  
                    <td>{{ data.Create_Date | date: "medium"}} </td> 
                    <td>{{ data.TAT}} </td> 
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </nz-table>
            </div>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
```

Comment: please provide some code, how your table is rendered in your html, what library are you using, and even better if you can provide a stackblitz link to what you are doing

Comment: Updated the HTML section

Comment: Thanks, now what is that nztable, provide url to the library

Comment: i am using the nz-table features from nz-zorro.The critical part is the first bock of codes i posted originally. Mapping TAT to o is adding the entire array of TAT to each row of o. i need to add individual row level TAT to each row in o